# PHP error on joining table says not unique table or alias

Tags: php

I don't know how to fix this thing a little help would be good.

> Error : table/alias is not unique.

Why do i got this error? I believe why joins are correct.Please help

```
 $q = "SELECT * FROM `curriculum` "
   . "INNER JOIN `subject` ON `curriculum`.`subject`=`subject`.`sub_id` "
   . "LEFT JOIN `subject` ON `curriculum`.`cur_pr`=`subject`.`sub_id` "
   . "WHERE `course`=:cid and `cur_year`=1";
```

Comment: Post your table schema

Answer (score 0):

Change your Code to

```
 $q = "SELECT * FROM `curriculum` AS A "
   . "INNER JOIN `subject` AS B ON `A`.`subject`=`B`.`sub_id` "
   . "LEFT JOIN `subject` AS C ON `A`.`cur_pr`=`C`.`sub_id` "
   . "WHERE `course`=:cid and `cur_year`=1";
```

If you want to join Same tables again use `Table Aliases` Here `AS` is used to this purpose

Comment: wow..that's fast. It's working now.thanks a lot man..really save me a lot of time.

Comment: Have a nice a day!! If this answer is useful then please accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

You get an error that says table/alias is not unique because this line code:

> . "LEFT JOIN `subject` ON `curriculum`.`cur_pr`=`subject`.`sub_id` "

It don't know what subject is belong to what table ( first one or the second one). You can try this code above

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM `curriculum` AS cu "
   . "INNER JOIN `subject` AS su1 ON `cu`.`subject`=`su1`.`sub_id` "
   . "LEFT JOIN `subject` AS su2 ON `cu`.`cur_pr`=`su2`.`sub_id` "
   . "WHERE `cu.course`=:cid and `cu.cur_year`=1";
```